# Return data frame index with minimum number of rows from a subsetted list

Tags: r, list, subset, min

I have an original list a of 4 data frames a1,a2,a3 and a4.

Now, I subset list a in a new list b of 2 data frames containing a1 and a4 from list a.
I would like to find the corresponding list a index of the data frame in list b which has minimum number of rows in list b.

So, comparing the number of rows of data frames in list b (a1 and a4), the result should be 4, because a4 his the data frame with the smallest number of rows in list b and because a4 has index 4 in list a.

```
a1<-data.frame(v1=c(1,2,3),v2=c(1,2,3),v3=c(1,2,3))
a2<-data.frame(v1=c(),v2=c(),v3=c())
a3<-data.frame(v1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),v2=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),v3=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
a4<-data.frame(v1=c(1),v2=c(1),v3=c(1))
a<-list(a1,a2,a3,a4)

b<-a[c(1,4)]
```

I have tried to do:

```
which.min(sapply(b,nrow))
```

Doing in my way, I get the index of a4 (the data frame with minimum number of rows) in list b.
I would like to get instead the LIST A INDEX of the minimum number of rows data frame in list b.

Note: the minimum rows operation happens in list b.

Answer (score 2):

If the dataframes in `a` would have different number of rows for all of them, one way could be to find the minimum number of rows in `b` and find `which` element in `a` has the same number of rows.

```
which(min(sapply(b, nrow)) == sapply(a, nrow))
#[1] 4
```

However, a better full proof method would be to first find the dataframe with minimum number of rows in `b` and find which dataframe in `a` is `identical` to it.

```
min_df <- b[[which.min(sapply(b, nrow))]]
which(sapply(a, function(x) identical(min_df, x)))
#[1] 4
```

**EDIT**

Another approach could be

```
min_index <- which.min(sapply(b, nrow))
which(sapply(a, identical, b[[min_index]]) & seq_along(a) > min_index)
```

Comment: I tried to find the dataframe with minimum number of rows and find which dataframe in a is identical in a. However, if list a has more identical data frame to the one I found before, what do you suggested to do? For example, lets say list a has 4  empty data frames a1, a2, a3 and a4. I subset it and I get list b with data frames a1 and a4. Now, supposing the data frame with minimum number of rows is a4 (could also be a1 in this case), how do I retrieve a4 index in list a?

Comment: @David If you are trying to do it based on number of rows then there is no difference in either `a1` or `a4` because both of them have 0 rows. Using `which` will give you all the index in `a` which match with that in `b`. If you want only one, you can use `which.max` which will return the 1st match.

Comment: Yes, but what if would like to get the 4th match in a, even if the other data frame are same? Because in my code list b is subsetted from list a based on a certain condition. The lowest number of rows is essentially another condition to "filter" the original list a but applied to b which is the result of another filtering condition. At the end, I get a single data frame which is the result of all conditions and where I rbind a row. This final data frame will replace the old one in list a.

Comment: @David It is not exactly clear to me the reason behind selecting 4th over 1st. However, I updated one method in which you can check the index along with the dataframe match.

Comment: I have tried working on it and I appreciate your help. However, your new approach is not working, giving me back the wrong index(indexes) of list a. What are you trying to do with seq_along(a) > min_index ?

Comment: Can you tell me on what basis do you select 1st dataframe over 4th if all of them have the same rows?